# Installation fails on "choose and install softwares"

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I am trying to install debian on my new laptop (lenovo G5O 70) and I get an error on the step "choose and install softwares".

The installation apears to be stuck on execution of triggers of udev.

Comment: maybe driver issue...can you provide any more details

Comment: specifically to help you we would need to see the contents of the syslog which can be seen on virtual console four.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unetbooin provided a wrong installation image.

I used Rufus and everything works fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Anthon this _is_ an answer. What makes you think it isn't? What's more, this is _the_ answer since it is the OP themselves posting it! It is quite common that using one tool to create3 a bootable USB fails for distro X while using another tool works. This is what happened here.